# Joining some projects in one

Tags: c#

I have 30 projects in C# - `SomeProject_1, SomeProject_2 ... SomeProject_30`. And I need join all to one new project that include only 30 buttons to open the each project. It's possible?

Comment: Like a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "join all to one new project"? Do you want to use a Visual Studio solution (.sln file), or copy all of the .cs classes from each of your projects into one new project?

Comment: What do you mean by "that include only 30 buttons to open the each project"?

Answer (score 1):

As Dor Cohen said, this is what [solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h970wzkb.aspx) are for:

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Open the New Project dialog (even though we're not creating a new project) via File > New > Project...
3. Under "Installed Templates" on the left, expand "Other Project Types" and select "Visual Studio Solutions"
4. In the main list, select "Blank Solution"
5. Give it a filename and location, then click OK to create it
6. In the resulting blank solution, right-click the solution and choose Add > Exiting project..., choosing the existing project you want to add
7. Repeat step 6 for the other 29 projects
8. Save the solution

Now, when you open the one solution, all 30 projects are opened.

Comment: Thank you for good idea to create new project and copy all code from each. But it's a lot of work (each project contains some forms with thousands of rows). Can I create a new project in Visual Studio - simple form with 30 buttons - and join each button to each project (.sln files)? Thanks.

Comment: @ornald: I'm not suggesting that you copy the code. 1. Create a blank solution. 2. Use "Add project" to add the project to the solution. Yes, you'll have to do that for each project (30 times). Then, when you open the solution, all the projects are shown in the solution explorer.

Comment: Thank you - it's nice and simple - I was foolish:)

Comment: Maybe, will be useful - I opened new project Windows Form Application (Form1) and added 30 buttons. In Solution Explorer - right click to References/Add Reference/Browse - find .exe of each project (in folder Debug), then added to click of each button code [Name of added .exe].Form1 f1 = new Test.Form1(); f1.Show();

Comment: I apologize - instead new Test.Form1() - new [Name of added .exe].Form1()

Answer (score -3):

Make exe of each solution. Then,

As  you said, going to add 30 buttons, you can give simple command to buttons as:

```
Process.Start(exePath)
```

By this you can start each process in 30 different buttons.

Referance:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx